# DOM manipulation when the value of trigger change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-events

What's the best way to do this kind of manipulation case :

When the trigger using the combo box is **change**, I want to change the type of the textField that has previously been added to the form.

My sample **data collection** :

```
function DataProvide(){
    selectValues = { 
        "choose"        : "-Choose-",
        "id"            : "ID",
        "emp_name"      : "Employee Name",
        "photo_path"    : "Photo Path",
        "emp_id"        : "Employee ID",
        "start_date"    : "Start Date",
        "birth_date"    : "Birth Date"
    };

    $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {   
         $('#data1_1')
             .append($("<option></option>")
             .attr("value",key)
             .text(value)); 
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     DataProvide();
});
```

Data has been displayed in the combobox.

Then I add a field to a form using the **$.append()**

```
var count = 1;
$(".addCF").click(function(){
    count += 1;
    var $row = $('<tr>' 
    + '<td>' + '</td>'
    + '<td>' + '<input id="data2_' + count + '" type="text" name="data2[]" class="data2" value="" placeholder=""/>' + '</td>' 
    + '<td>' + '<input id="data3_' + count + '" type="text" name="data3[]" class="data3" value="" placeholder=""/>' + '</td>' 
    + '<td>' + '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a>' + '</td>' 
    + '</tr>').appendTo("#customFields");
    $row.find('td:first').append($('#data1_1').clone())
});

    $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        count -= 1;
    });
```

[image: View]

Until this point I've been as successful as I want.

But I want to make a small change to 3rd column. How best way to manipulate this form when **trigger (combo box)** that I select for example "**start_date**" then the field will be changed to use the class "**onlyDate**" that I add jQuery UI to display the date options.

I added :

```
$(".onlyDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});
```

Then to check the value of the **combo**
$("#customFields").on('change', '.tabelBaru', function() {

```
if(nilai=='gender'){
            $this.closest("tr").find(".data3").replaceWith(
                '<select name="data3[]" class="data3">'
                    + '<option value="man" selected >Man</option>'
                    + '<option value="woman">Woman</option>'
                + '</select>'
            )
        }else if(nilai=='start_date'){
            $this.closest("tr").find(".data3").replaceWith(
                '<input type="text" name="data3[]" value="" class="onlyDate"/>'
            )
        }
};
```

But jQueryUI datepicker **does not appear** as usual. But if the normal form (without using $.append) all running normally.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".onlyDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});
```

When this code execute, it will only find out that current statement's object whit class name onlyDate.

After that any object with class name onlyDate append on the page won't execute the datepick code.

Maybe you should try out jquery function "delegate" or execute the datepicker code after each append.

Comment: I use $("table").on("click", ".onlyDate", function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
  });
 });

Comment: But every time I change the combo box the second time this happened recently. I mean if I select the combo box "start_date" DateTime does not work, but if I choose another combo then DatePicker is successfully displayed. What do I miss?

Comment: It's because that code will bind the click event on the .onlyDate Object.
So the first time you finishing click the item, it finally become the datepicker ojbect you want.(Before the first click, it still only a normal intput:text object)